# Why can't I assign i equals to 0?

Tags: c

In this program, if I assign `i=0`, then why do I get `-8320909` instead of a sorted array, and yet if I assign the value to `1` it works fine? So what makes this change?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Bubblesort(int *A, int n) {
    int i, j, temp;
    for (i = 1; i <= n - 1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= n - i - 1; j++) {
            if (A[j] > A[j + 1]) {
                temp = A[j];
                A[j] = A[j + 1];
                A[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The idiomatic C `for` loop uses `for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)` where limit is sometimes an expression. It covers values `0 .. (limit - 1)`.  Using `<` and not `<=` is important.  Your problem has been correctly identified by [Thomas Jager](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5567382/thomas-jager) in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55994985/15168) — you are accessing beyond the end of the array.

Answer (score 3):

When `i` is 0, then the condition `j <=n-i - 1` is still true when `j == n - 1`. However, you index into `A` at index `j + 1`, which is one past the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go from `i` to `n - 1` exclusive and from `j` to `n - i - 1` exclusive as well, otherwise you will go out of bounds and invoke undefined behavior. So change:

```
i<=n-1;
```

to

```
i < n - 1;
```

and

```
j <=n-i - 1;
```

to

```
j < n - i - 1;
```

Comment: But this does not give sorted array. If I input array 5,4,3,2,1 than it give me 2,3,4,5,1.

Comment: @sagar Then you need to set `i` to `0` instead of `1` in `for (i = 1; i <= n - 1; i++)` because indexing starts from `0` in C.